# Matching column with words separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I have a category column with values separated by comma, ie, "menu, brochure". How can I retrieve row which is matching either menu or brochure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) or [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)